# Select every Nth entry from bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to retrieve every Nth word from a bash array. Consider the following array definition:

```
words=("word1" "word2" "word3" "word4" "word5" "word6")
```

I would like to select words taken from the array at the interval given by a variable's value (whitespace is for clarity, and not to indicate that output needs to be aligned):

```
n=1 # select items: word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6
n=2 # select items:       word2       word4       word6
n=3 # select items:             word3             word6
n=4 # select items:                   word4
```

How can this be done?

Comment: for (( i = 0; i<${#words[@]}; i+=$get_words )); do echo ${words[$i]}; done

Comment: Are you intending `//` to be a comment character? If so, `#` would be more clear.

Comment: BTW, "multiple specific words" didn't say *how* the words are specified -- we had to infer that, as originally asked. I've tried to edit to make the question less ambiguous; when asking questions in the future, please try to be specific and clear up-front, rather than relying on readers to infer from examples.

Answer (score 4):

As [Danila Kiver described in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274350/bash-print-multiple-specific-words/51274530#comment89527152_51274350), the following will work so long as your array is numerically indexed and not sparse:

```
for ((i=n-1; i<${#words[@]}; i+=n)); do
  echo "${words[$i]}"
done
```